# Dashes doesn't start full at the beginning in circle svg

Tags: css, svg, path, stroke, stroke-dasharray

I want to create a dashed progress circle for grades. I want to make the length of dashes function of the grade max. (Ex : if the grade is 3.5/5, the dashes will be 24px long).

The problem is that the first dash (the one on top right) is not at the wanted length.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" [attr.viewBox]="_getViewBox()">

  <!-- The grey circle plain for background-->
  <path
  #background
  fill="none"
  [style.stroke-width]="stroke"
  [style.stroke]="'#EAEAEA'"
  [attr.transform]="getPathTransform()"/>

  <!-- The blue circle plain for progress -->
  <path
  #path
  fill="none"
  [style.stroke-width]="stroke"
  [style.stroke]="resolveColor(color)"
  [attr.transform]="getPathTransform()"/>

  <!-- The white dashed circle for delimitation of dashes -->
  <path
  #dash
  fill="none"
  [style.stroke-width]="stroke"
  [style.stroke]="'#ffffff'"
  stroke-dasharray="4.3,23.7"
  [attr.transform]="getPathTransform()"/>
</svg>
```

note that if i keep this value on the last path > stroke-dasharray="4.3,23.7" i get this :
[image: good progress circle]

But it's just because i came accross the good value to put here for a radius of 70. Because if i want to change it (to make it function of the max grade for exemple) i have this :

[image: wrong image]

What i want is to have a coherent value for the number of dashes and for the length of dashes, and i'm a little lost, i don't know what to do

Comment: So, what is the system? 3.3/5 should be 14 dashes and 12/20 should be 25 dashes for a fill circle -- is that right? what is the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I use a mask to create the stroke-dasharray. The dasharray is calculated based on the max-score (total). There is always a gap of 5 units between dashes (out of a total/pathLength of 1000).

The mask is then applied to two circles. The gray circle is always a full circle and the length of the DarkTurquoise circle depends on the score.

Both circles are rotated -90 deg, so that the score 0 is at 12 o click.

```js
const c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
const c2 = document.getElementById('c2');
const t1 = document.getElementById('t1');

const update = (total, score) => {
  c1.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${(1000-total*5)/total} 5`);
  c2.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${1000/total*score} 1000`);
  t1.textContent = `${score}/${total}`;
};

document.forms.form01.total.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let total = parseInt(e.target.value);
  let score = parseInt(e.target.form.score.value);
  e.target.form.score.setAttribute('max', total);
  if (score >= total) score = total;
  update(total, score);
});

document.forms.form01.score.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let total = parseInt(e.target.form.total.value);
  let score = parseInt(e.target.value);
  update(total, score);
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>Total: <input name="total" type="range" min="5" max="30" value="10"/></label>
  <label>Score: <input name="score" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5"/></label>
</form>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask01">
      <circle id="c1" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="95 5" pathLength="1000"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g transform="rotate(-90 50 50)">
  <circle mask="url(#mask01)" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="none" stroke="Gainsboro" stroke-width="10" />
  <circle id="c2" mask="url(#mask01)" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="none" stroke="DarkTurquoise" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="500 1000" pathLength="1000" />
  </g>
  <text id="t1" x="50" y="50" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif" fill="DarkTurquoise">5/10</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want to do ! Thank you very much !! I have to test it but i wonder what happen if i put a decimal value. Thank you again

Comment: @AG floating numbers are fine in SVG. But the "dashes" in the example are based on values that matches the split between them.

Comment: Just for the record, it works perfectly with decimal values ! I'm trying to do the same thing but with a line progress bar but i can't make it work.. Is your way to do with mask could also work ?

Comment: @AG a `<line>` can also have a dasharray, so if you have the same setup with dashes and the two colors I guess it could work. Only problem: line it has no pathLength attibute, so maybe it is easier to go with a straight path like: `<path d="M 0 0 H 60" pathLength="1000"/>`.

Comment: @AG example with a path: https://codepen.io/chrwahl/pen/GRMaKKR